# Connect ECONNREFUSED message on Debian but works on Windows

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, node.js

I wrote some javascript to delegate messages from XBMC to my Dune mediaplayer. So i am starting on windows with a batch file that executes my javascript with Node.js code in it.

start.bat:

```
@echo off
node \Users\Flo\Desktop\file.js %1
```

file.js:

```
var http = require("http");

var filepath = process.argv[2].substring(6);
filepath = filepath.replace(/\\/g,"/");

var dcmd = "http://dune/cgi-bin/do?cmd=start_file_playback&media_url=storage_name:/" + filepath;

http.get(dcmd, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
  var bodyarr = [];

  res.on('data', function(chunk){
    bodyarr.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on('end', function(){
    console.log(bodyarr.join('').toString());
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Everthing works fine with this setup.
But now i want to do this on a Raspbian system with a shell script.

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
nodejs /usr/local/bin/file.js $1
```

And i am always getting the error: connect ECONNREFUSED
Why?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What host is `dune` supposed to resolve to? What is listening on port 80 there? On which IP?

Comment: It's the Dune Wen API in my home lan. The ip is 192.168.1.234. But i think this doesn't care because i can do a get request with curl command in shell and get a xml response.

Comment: Are you making that curl request from the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes. I have Windows on my desktop and Raspbian on the Raspberry Pi. I am doing the curl from a ssh connection to the pi.